# How does one calculate a re-bounce sling shot trajectory such a Juno?

Tags: classical-mechanics

looking at this https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoGbU.gif [image]

What text book would allow one to calculate such things? DE books in university certainly had nothing that could be of use with such calculations.

how does one even knows that when such trajectories will be possible to calculate them?

Comment: Did they really calculate it analyticly? Or did they calculate it using numerics?

Comment: most likely numerically, but when do you know that such trajwctory is possible to calculate it @MrYouMath , unless they calculate all possiblities.

Comment: [Related SX question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/10021/)

Comment: Some Refs: [Incremental Planning of multi-gravity-assist trajectories](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/265694621_Incremental_Planning_of_Multi-Gravity_Assist_Trajectories), [A graphical method for gravity-assist trajectory design](https://engineering.purdue.edu/people/james.m.longuski.1/ConferencePapersPresentations/2000AGraphicalMethodforGravity-AssistTrajectoryDesign.pdf). It's not trivial, but you can get far with simplifications.

Comment: @Arjang: you first need the differential equations describing the motion. I think the related partial differential equations are nonlinear. So you will need to solve it by numerical methods. I dont think that there is know simple way to show that the trajectories will not cross for all times. I also think thet you would do online calcuations to control/adapt the motion so that you can land on jupiter.